# VBA excel , improve performance without loops

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I have two identical sheets that i want to take the rows of , that are identical in multiple columns (the sheets are 63 columns always and 504 rows and increasing) , i am using two for loops to increase the row in one and then comparing all the rows in the other with that row then increase the row again and compare all the rows of the other with that row ect. till the last row , then an if loop to see if they match my conditions . The problem is that it is taking too much time (about 8 mins) , i tried to use the lookup functions but it failed because it can only take one value . I added the false screenupdating , calculation , and enableevents and even changed the statusbar to something very basic to improve performance but non of them gave me the result I wanted .

How can i improve performance in any way possible , a new function or anything ??

PS some times some of the conditions are not important and it depends on the true or fasle values on some of the cells .

```
For Row_S = 2 To MAX_Row_S
  SourceMonth = Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, SOP).Value
  SourceMonth = DatePart("m", SourceMonth)
  SourceYear = Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, SOP).Value
  SourceYear = DatePart("yyyy", SourceYear)
  SourceCarmaker = Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, carmaker).Value
  SourceProject = Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, Project).Value
  SourceFamily = Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, Family).Value
  SourceStatus = Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, Status).Value
  SourceShare = Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, Share).Value
  SourceCst = Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, "A").Value
  SourcePID = Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, ProjectID).Value

  ' Take the data from NBG_Data_Region sheet to be Compared with each row of the NBG_Data_Source_Region sheet
  For Row_T = 2 To MAX_Row_T
    If Row_T >= MAX_Row_T Then
        Exit For
    End If

    NBGMonth = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, SOP).Value
    NBGMonth = DatePart("m", NBGMonth)
    NBGYear = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, SOP).Value
    NBGYear = DatePart("yyyy", NBGYear)
    NBGCarmaker = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, carmaker).Value
    NBGProject = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, Project).Value
    NBGFamily = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, Family).Value
    NBGStatus = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, Status).Value
    NBGShare = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, Share).Value
    NBGCst = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, "A").Value
    NBGPID = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, ProjectID).Value

    ' StatusBar Show
    Application.StatusBar = "Running"
    'Application.StatusBar = "VerifyMultipleCustomerProjects. Progress: " & Row_S & " of " & MAX_Row_S
    ' Check if any project in the NBG_Data_Region have multiple customers and add it ti the sheet Issue_MultipleCustomerProjects

    ' NAF 20161208

    'Test with Source of YEAR and MONTH
     If ((NBGMonth = SourceMonth Or Worksheets(Issue_MultipleCustomerProjectsWorksheetName).Range("C21") = True) And _
        (NBGYear = SourceYear Or Worksheets(Issue_MultipleCustomerProjectsWorksheetName).Range("C25") = True) And _
        (SourceCarmaker = NBGCarmaker Or Worksheets(Issue_MultipleCustomerProjectsWorksheetName).Range("G25") = True) And _
        (SourceProject = NBGProject Or Worksheets(Issue_MultipleCustomerProjectsWorksheetName).Range("F25") = True) And _
        (SourceFamily = NBGFamily Or Worksheets(Issue_MultipleCustomerProjectsWorksheetName).Range("E25") = True) And _
        (SourceShare + NBGShare <> 1 Or Worksheets(Issue_MultipleCustomerProjectsWorksheetName).Range("H25") = True) And NBGCst <> SourceCst) Then
```

Comment: Use arrays instead of constently access the sheet.  Load everything into two arrays and output the data to another array that you will post back one time.  That way you only access the sheets three times.  It cut the run time into the seconds.

Comment: I'd load the data into arrays. you can then pull both sets of data off the sheet in one transaction each, then do any comparisons you want between the arrays. As it stands you're doing around 2.8 million transactions which would explain the speed problems. - @Scott Craner, posted same time but It's great you had the exact same logic :)

Comment: @ScottCraner  thank you , array work is a bit tricky but i am working on it , wish me luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

at the beginning of your code, and

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

at the end of your code?

This will turn off screen updating, events, and alerts causing faster run-time.

Also, loading and unloading arrays are the fastest way if you decide to take that route.

An example of loading an array:

```
Dim arr() As Variant ' let brackets empty, not Dim arr(1) As Variant !

For Each a In Range.Cells
    ' change / adjust the size of array
    ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr) + 1) As Variant

    ' add value on the end of the array
    arr(UBound(arr)) = a.Value
Next
```

An example of iterating through the array to pull your data:

```
For Each element In arr 'Each array element
    do_something (element)
Next element
```

Comment: i did but the run time decreased by few seconds , can you please explain the loading and unloading arrays ??

Comment: @NasserAlFanek Please see my updated answer as I have provided an example.

Comment: thank you very much for clearing that , i will start with the array use , thanks .

Comment: just two questions , how can i insert values only from certain columns that i assign , and can i have strings and integers in my array ??